# How to make a dictionary from a datset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-xarray

I have a dataset `AllStations` that contains daily temperature data for 225 grid points. I want to turn this into a dictionary where the keys are the dataset index (AllStations.index) and the values are the corresponding temperature values (AllStations.tmax). I.e. I want a dictionary that has 225 keys, from `AllStations` index and the values should be 25933 corresponding temperature values for each index. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: We need a little more information in order to help you. First, how do you get "the data set index (grid points)" from this dataset? Second, how do you get the temperature values?

Comment: I updated the question to answer those questions. The index is AllStations.index and temperature values are AllStations.tmax

Comment: If the dict key is an index, then it is basically just a list... We need more info about what `AllStations` value type is (is it a `pandas` `dataframe`?). I would use `time` as the dict key if they are all unique.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the data to a DataFrame and then use the [`pd.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method:

```py
AllStations.to_dataframe().tmax.unstack('index').to_dict(orient='series')
```

Alternatively, you could keep things in xarray and convert indices to data variables, which would give you dictionary-like access to each variable:

```py
AllStations.tmax.to_dataset(dim='index')
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! The problem now is that time is labeled, but tmax is not. How can I make it so that tmax retains its name. I ultimately want to be able to create a dataframe of each dictionary value that has columns time and tmax

Comment: you could loop through all the elements and convert the series to dataframes... this is getting to be a really strange data structure. there's definitely no xarray to dictionary of dataframes method so it's going to take some manual work no matter what.